# Spring Data JPA - repository findAll method using flag column

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I want to use the method findAll in a repository, but I`d like it to return just entities which have a certain value. For example, I want it to return just entities which are active = 1. Is there a way to do that?

Now I have to write for all my repositories something like this:

```
@Query("select p from Parameter p where p.active = 1")
public List<Parameter> findAll();
```

Instead of using the findOne method I have to write this in all my repositories:

```
@Query("select p from Parameter p where p.active = 1 and p.id=?1")
public Parameter findById(Long id);
```

Is there a better way to apply a blanket filter to all queries?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at hibernate Filters.

Comment: @jervine10 Using Hibernate Filters is really a great idea.

Comment: I think I found a good and elegant solution on the spring-data-jpa docs. I consists on using the SpEL expression #{#entityName}, creating a generic repository and than extending this interface for my concrete entities repositories.

Thanks

Answer (score 26):

If you could consider moving from findAll to another strategy, look at the docs here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.sample-app.finders.strategies

> The JPA module supports defining a query manually as String or have it being derived from the method name.

So in your case if you want to retrieve all entities where active = 1, you can write something like:

```
public List<Parameter> findByActive(Integer active);
```

And you can also compose the method name in this way:

```
public Parameter findByIdAndActive(Long id, Integer active);
```

The translation between the method signature to the query to be executed is automatic.

**Edit:** If you are using boolean for active you can also have methods like

```
public List<Parameter> findByActiveTrue();
//or
public List<Parameter> findByActiveFalse();
```

Comment: If You put `public Parameter findByActive(Integer active)`, will this look for the first row with the `active` value equal to the argument?
How would one achieve that, if not like this?

Comment: @Fabio Maffioletti what about to order the result based on a specific column?

Comment: @Adly you add `OrderBy` to the method name. For example: `findByActiveOrderByName` where “Name" is the upper cased property of the object you want us for sorting.

Comment: @FabioMaffioletti Saviour:)